# unable to retrieve the visualforce page tab

Tags: visualforce, tab, package.xml, custom-tab

I want to retrieve and deploy the `custom visualforce tab page` from salesforce environment. I tried so far the following piece of the block in `package.xml` but could not retrieve the custom visualforce page.

```
 <types>
    <members>VOIP_Settings</members>
    <name>CustomTab</name>
</types>
```

This block allows to fetch custom tab but it seems it is not fetching the custom visualforce page tab. I tried to hunt a lot but could not find a way to retrieve the visualforce custom tab from the org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve it like this:

```
<types>
  <members>TabName.tab</members>
  <name>CustomTab</name>
</types>
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_tab.htm)